# putexcel error - formatting options not allowed

Tags: format, export-to-excel, stata

I export my matrix (one column) with following:

```
putexcel set exc.xlsx , replace sheet(primo)
putexcel B2=matrix(P3, names)
```

and it creates an Excel file without problems. However, if I want to format it, with for example:

```
putexcel (B3:C3), bold border(bottom)
```

I get error "198 option not allowed"... I work in Stata 13.1. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel cell formatting was introduced to Stata in version 14. The `putexcel` command works in Stata 13, but does not allow you to make any formatting changes. See the official Stata 14 release announcement here:

http://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/
and here specifically for cell formatting:
http://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/excel-cell-formatting/